# map_dfr: populate .id column with string labels instead of indices without .x named

Tags: r, purrr

I want to label the `.id` column entries in the output of `map_dfr` with words instead of index values, but my input is not named (which is [how `map` accepts string values for `.id`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html)).

What's the best way to map names into the `.id` field in this case?

Example data:

```
n <- 20
df <- data.frame(foo_1=rnorm(n), foo_2=rnorm(n), foo_3=rnorm(n), 
                 foo_a=runif(n), t_foo=runif(n),
                 bar_1=rnorm(n), bar_2=rnorm(n), bar_3=rnorm(n), 
                 bar_a=runif(n), t_bar=runif(n))
```

Both `foo` and `bar` are psychometric scales, and I want to take a measure of reliability for each scale, using `psych::alpha()`.
The only relevant columns have the naming pattern `foo_<int>` (for the `foo` scale) or `bar_<int>` for the `bar` scale (hence the regex match below).

In reality I have many scales, and many columns that make up each scale.  So I thought `map` might be a good way to carry out the computations, something like this:

```
require(psych)
require(tidyverse)

categories <- c("foo", "bar")

categories %>%
  map_dfr(~df %>% 
            select(matches(paste0("^",.x,"_?\\d"))) %>% 
            do(psych::alpha(., check.keys=TRUE)$total), .id="scale") %>%
  select(scale, raw_alpha, std.alpha)

  scale raw_alpha std.alpha
1     1 0.2275679 0.2791238
2     2 0.4141225 0.4130054
```

But I want `scale` to take values `foo` and `bar`:

```
  scale raw_alpha std.alpha
1   foo 0.2275679 0.2791238
2   bar 0.4141225 0.4130054
```

In this toy example, it wouldn't be so bad to just manually create `categories <- c(foo="foo", bar="bar")`, but with many scales that requires too much effort.

One thought I had was to automate the `foo="foo"` approach with something like `zip` from Python, to create a vector of key-value pairs, eg `c(scale_name="scale_name",...)`, but I don't know how to do that in R.  And in any case, that approach isn't very pretty (although I'd happily settle for merely functional).

Any suggestions for how to best get the output format I'm looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something more complex with the problem, it's an easy fix. You can just add `mutate` inside the `map_dfr`, so you're making a column based on the value passed into `map_dfr`. You could just drop the `.id` bit and use a `mutate` call to make the `scale` column; I just wanted to show `scale` and `scale_cat` side by side.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
n <- 20
df <- data.frame(foo_1=rnorm(n), foo_2=rnorm(n), foo_3=rnorm(n), 
                                 foo_a=runif(n), t_foo=runif(n),
                                 bar_1=rnorm(n), bar_2=rnorm(n), bar_3=rnorm(n), 
                                 bar_a=runif(n), t_bar=runif(n))

categories <- c("foo", "bar")

categories %>%
    map_dfr(~df %>% 
                        select(matches(paste0("^",.x,"_?\\d"))) %>% 
                        do(psych::alpha(., check.keys=TRUE)$total) %>%
                        mutate(scale_cat = .x), 
                    .id="scale") %>%
    select(scale, scale_cat, raw_alpha, std.alpha)
#>   scale scale_cat raw_alpha std.alpha
#> 1     1       foo 0.2606448 0.2601066
#> 2     2       bar 0.4571981 0.4827263
```

Created on 2018-05-12 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks, seems obvious now.  Staring at the problem for too long!